# Unexpected behaviour of greater and less than

Tags: r, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Can anyone explain to me, why R answers `FALSE` in the following case?

```
(1-0.9)>=0.1
```

How can I get `TRUE` for comparisons of that kind?

Comment: The most frequently asked FAQ 7.32: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own binary operators to do what you're after and store them in your .Rprofile:

```
`%>=%` <- function(x, y) all.equal(x, y) | x > y
`%<=%` <- function(x, y) all.equal(x, y) | x < y

c(1-.9)>=.1
c(1-.9)%>=% .1
```

Comment: +1, neat trick to do this kind of comparison. Maybe `~=` would be an even better name.

Answer (score 5):

This is the classic [R FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). You need `all.equal`

Comment: +1, however I added some details in my answer to make this question somewhat self contained.

Comment: 7.31 surely? Floating point and off-by-one errors combined!

Comment: thanks. I've edited to make less a fool of myself

Answer (score 5):

This has to do with floating point precision. There is in essence an infinite amount of floating points, do representing them in the computer can only be done discretely, and thus with limited precision. To take this limited precision into account, use `all.equal` to make the comparison. As @RomainFracois said, this is very frequently asked question in R.